# How to insert a wildcard in an OpenOCD adapter interface driver command?

Tags: shell, tcl, openocd

I'd like to use the adapter interface driver command `ftdi_serial` in OpenOCD where the argument has a wildcard. This is because the serial number field will not be static from device to device in my application.

So instead of passing:

`ftdi_serial AXG_09876`

I'd like to pass:

`ftdi_serial AXG*` where `*` is the wildcard.  The problem is, I haven't been able to identify what character is the wildcard character for openOCD.  It certainly isn't `*`.  Maybe there isn't one?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a way to list what the current possible arguments are?

Comment: @DonalFellows  Thanks for your reply.  If there's a way to query that info, I'm not aware of it.  If you have a suggestion though, I'd give it a try.

Comment: IMHO, `ftdi_serial` is intended to select one specific adapter from a set of connected simultaneously. If someone want to use any (one) connected they should use `ftdi_vid_pid`, `ftdi_device_desc`.

Comment: @ReAl I ended up just using `ftdi_device_desc`